# Why is model.matrix so slow?

Tags: r, matrix, lm, model.matrix

Consider the following demo data:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000000
x1 <- rnorm(n)
x2 <- rnorm(n)
x3 <- rnorm(n)
```

If I build a matrix `mt` with `model.matrix()`, it takes forever:

```
system.time(mt <- model.matrix(~x1+x2+x3))
usuário   sistema decorrido 
 0.916     0.185     1.135
```

But if I do the same with matrix, it is pretty fast:

```
system.time(mt2 <- matrix(c(rep(1, n), x1, x2, x3), byrow=FALSE, ncol=4))
 usuário   sistema decorrido 
  0.085     0.021     0.105
```

Why the difference? Is what makes `model.matrix()` slow really necessary for `lm()` and related functions?

Comment: Matrix is just making a matrix of existing elements. No operations are performed. Try `debugonce(stats:::model.matrix.default)` and step through it to see how much it's doing.

Comment: I did it. It did not throw much light on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `debugonce(model.matrix.default)`, and within this using `tracemem(data)`

`model.matrix.default` calls `model.frame` which returns a `data.frame`. Within `model.matrix.default`, this data.frame is copied at least 3 times.

Why does `lm` use `model.matrix` --> `lm` is usually called with a `data.frame` , `list` or  `environment` as the `data` argument. `model.frame` and returning a `data.frame` ensures that terms in the formula can be found by subsequent calls to `lm`, and will reference the same values.

Comment: It seems that those operations are kind of a bottleneck for big datasets. Try with 10 million obs.

Comment: @carloscinelli, for big data sets, it is probably a better Idea to use [biglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html) anyway

Answer (score 1):

In general, a call to `Rprof` (in `library(utils)` which should be on the `search()` path by default) will illustrate where the overhead in time is coming from in a function call:

```
Rprof("Rprof.out")
m1 <- model.matrix( ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("Rprof.out")
```

giving

```
> summaryRprof("Rprof.out")
$by.self
                        self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"model.matrix.default"       0.12    42.86       0.28    100.00
"na.omit.data.frame"         0.06    21.43       0.14     50.00
"[.data.frame"               0.04    14.29       0.08     28.57
"anyDuplicated.default"      0.04    14.29       0.04     14.29
"as.list.data.frame"         0.02     7.14       0.02      7.14

$by.total
                        total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"model.matrix.default"        0.28    100.00      0.12    42.86
"model.matrix"                0.28    100.00      0.00     0.00
"na.omit.data.frame"          0.14     50.00      0.06    21.43
"model.frame"                 0.14     50.00      0.00     0.00
"model.frame.default"         0.14     50.00      0.00     0.00
"na.omit"                     0.14     50.00      0.00     0.00
"[.data.frame"                0.08     28.57      0.04    14.29
"["                           0.08     28.57      0.00     0.00
"anyDuplicated.default"       0.04     14.29      0.04    14.29
"anyDuplicated"               0.04     14.29      0.00     0.00
"as.list.data.frame"          0.02      7.14      0.02     7.14
"as.list"                     0.02      7.14      0.00     0.00
"vapply"                      0.02      7.14      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 0.28
```

Thus a large amount of time is spent on checking for `NA`s with `na.omit.data.frame` and subsetting the `data.frame` with `[.data.frame`, within `model.frame.default`. The proportions of time will vary depending on the sample size `n`, but will tend towards a limit for large sample sizes.